# After running count query on influxdb entire system gets freeze and influx memory spikes up high

Tags: influxdb

I have 50 million rows in influxdb table, when i tried to run count query to get number of rows in my existing table, all other process gets killed because of OOM and finally influx gets shutdown with same reason. please suggest me a solution why it's hapenning?

Edit:

```
json_body_part = {
                        "measurement": "vehicleinfo",
                        "tags": {
                                "vehicleno": i["Vehicleno"],
                                "speed": i["Speed"],
                                },
                        "time": time,
                        "fields": {
                                "tracktime": i["Tracktime"],
                                "value":1,
                                "direction": i["direction"],
                                "geohash": geohash,
                                "latitude" : latitude,
                                "longitude" : longitude,
                                "odometer": i["odometer"],
                                "gpsstatus": i["gpsstatus"],
                                "ignition": i["ignition"],
                                }
                }
```

I'm using python influxdb client and these with these query OOM error occur:

```
query_str = "select count(*) from vehicleinfo" 
query_str = "select vehicleno from vehicleinfo where vehicleno='KA---****'"
```

(without limit and where clause its not returning any result and OOM occur.)

Comment: Are you sure OOM is actually caused by your query?
It might be some background influxdb process going wild. InfluxDB has plenty of OOM issues reported. https://community.influxdata.com/search?q=OOM

Comment: i have tested it 2 times, during the test my system gets freeze for around 15-20 minutes and i was not even able to do ssh to terminate the process.
-> Using netdata i have tested it, i executed the command and influxdb increasing its memory and after 10-15 sec everything goes down not even my netdata is working.

Comment: show the query, please, along with the schema you're using (tag keys + field keys for given measurement, at least)

Comment: Influxdb can OOM even for a dead simple query like SELECT * FROM meas LIMIT 1; (see https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9313). Check you logs - was there any tsm compaction running at the moment of query? What is your series cardinaliity (tags reverse index is kept totally in RAM)? I've switched to a more sane and predictable DB engine after encounting similar influx issues.